# If gcd$(a , b) = 1$, $ab|c$ implies $a|c$ and $b|c$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

As a consequence of Euclid's lemma we know that if gcd$(a,b)=1$ and $a|c$ and $b|c$, for some integer $c$, then $ab|c$. The converse is true? Why? I can't find this result or something similar anywhere.

Comment: Of course you can find this result, in any intro book in elementary number theory. The way it is stated is "if A divides B and B divides C, then A divides C". In your case: a divides ab (obviously) and ab divides c, so a divides c.

Comment: The converse is true for all a,b and not just relative prime a,b for obvious reasons. Just think about it for a second. ab|c so c = kab.  and a|ab (as ab = ab, duh.)  so does a|c=kab for some integer k?

Comment: This feels like a duplicate question... But I can't think of how to search for the "original" question.

Answer (score 2):

If $ab |c$ then $abk=c$ for some integer $k$

so $a(bk) = c$ and $b(ak)=c$

so $a|c$ and $b|c$

Comment: You do not need $\gcd(a,b)=1$, or as I prefer to write it $\operatorname{hcf}(a,b)=1$

Comment: @user236182: *"highest common factor"* is what it says, and means the same as *"greatest common divisor"* but uses nicer words; *"lowest common multiple"* means something else and is usually bigger.

Answer (score 1):

This can be restated as $abk = c$ for some integer $k$.

If we can divide the lefthand side by something, we can also divide the righthand side. We can obviously divide the left by $a$, $b$, $k$, and so on, so the righthand side can be divided by those things, too.